# Extract unevaluated definition of function

Tags: evaluation, hold

Say I have a function `f[x_]:=a x + b`.
Now I want to get the `a x + b` part from the function to use in e.g. `StringForm`.
This without using `HoldForm` or `Unevaluated` in the definition of `f`

That is, I want the function `ExpandOnce`:

```
In[1] := f[x_]:=a x + b
         StringForm["f(x)=``",ExpandOnce[f]]
Out[1]:= f(x)=a x + b
```

The above could work by using the `Definition` command, but that also includes the left hand side of the definition. It would also be great if it's not restricted to only definitions, but also any variable that holds an expression. E.g. `%`.

Any help appreciated.

I would expect this to be somewhere in this forum, but I've only found nuances of this.

Related links

- [Getting unevaluated function expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47559/getting-unevaluated-function-expression) This answer is very close, but not close enough, to what I would want. (I'm also fine with parsing `Definition`)
- [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression) *Very close*.

Comment: Try `ToString[DownValues[f][[1]] /. HoldPattern[lhs_ :> rhs_] :> HoldForm[rhs]]`.

Comment: That seem to work beautifully! Want to make it an answer?

Comment: Alternatively: `ToString[HoldForm[f[x]]/.DownValues[f]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More general than going through the `DownValues` would be to `Trace` the evaluation and look only at the first step,

```
f[x_] := a x + b
StringForm["f(x)=``", Trace[f[x]][[2]]]
```

> f(x)=a x + b

Of course if `Trace[f[x]]` is a huge affair, then this becomes very inefficient. Maybe the option `TraceDepth -> 1` will help here:

```
f[x_] := a x + b
StringForm["f(x)=``", Trace[f[x], TraceDepth -> 1][[2]]]
```

> f(x)=a x + b

For the `%` symbol the trace is longer, involving the lookup in the `Out` database. We must therefore go to the fourth evaluation step,

```
2 + 91
(* 93 *)
StringForm["%=``", Trace[%][[5]]]
```

> %=93

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `f` has only 1 downvalue, then you can use:

```
ExpandOnce[f] := Replace[
    DownValues[f][[1]],
    _[_, rhs_] :> HoldForm[rhs]
]
```

Your example:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := a x + b
StringForm["f(x)=``", ExpandOnce[f]]
```

> f(x)=a x+b

Note that contrary to the answers in the comments, I don't use [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) in the definition of `ExpandOnce`. I think using [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) is usually a bad idea, as something like the following can happen:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := 10^-7 x + 1/2
StringForm["f(x)=``", ToString @ ExpandOnce[f]]
```

> ```
> f(x)= x    1
> --- + -
>   7   2
> 10
> ```